# Real Analysis Question from Terence Tao's Book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was having trouble with what I believe to be a rather easy problem from section six of Terence Tao's Introduction to measure theory.  Help will be appreciated.

If $F$ is everywhere differentiable (and thus $F$ is continuous), show $F'$ is measurable.

Comment: full proof: https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/an_introduction_to_measure_theory/exercise_1-6-1

Answer (score 8):

Define:

$$
g_n(x) = \frac{F(x + 1/n) - F(x)}{1/n}
$$

This is a sequence of measurable functions. The pointwise limit as $n \to \infty$ is $F'$. Since the pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable, it follows that $F'$ is measurable.